# Problem with Implementing Merge Sort using an ArrayList

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting

When I execute the following code, for some reason I get

```java
java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
```

I have tried researching this exception and I believe it happens because the list is being continually edited while I am trying to access it yet again.

This is really frustrating because when I instead of using ArrayLists, used regular arrays, everything seemed to work fine, so I'm not exactly sure how I can go around using the same procedure just with array lists and get it to work.

Here's the code:

```java
public static void mergeSort(List<Integer> indexList, int listLen) {
        if (listLen < 2) {
            // calls merge method when 1 term is in either left or right arrays
            return;
        }

        int middlepoint = listLen / 2;
        List<Integer> leftArr = indexList.subList(0, middlepoint);
        List<Integer> rightArr = indexList.subList(middlepoint, listLen);

        // passing the numList to the merge (once all numbers are in groups of 1)
        merge(indexList, leftArr, rightArr, middlepoint, listLen - middlepoint);
    }

    public static void merge(
    List<Integer> numList, List<Integer> leftArr, List<Integer> rightArr, int left, int right) {
        // while there are terms in both lists
        int i = 0, j = 0, k = 0;

        // while numbers in both lists
        while (i < left && j < right) {
            int leftVal = leftArr.get(i);
            int rightVal = rightArr.get(j);

            // if the term in the right array is bigger/equal (filling the final list smallest to greatest)
            if (leftVal <= rightVal) {
                numList.add(k++, leftVal);
                i++;
            }
            else {
                numList.add(k++, rightVal);
                j++;
            }

            while (i < left) {
                numList.add(k++, leftVal); 
                i++;
            }
            while (j < right) {
                numList.add(k++, rightVal);
                j++;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have used subList to divide and traverse the List. Arraylist doesn't allow you to modify the values when you are in middle of traversal and throws an Concurrent Modification Exception.

One way of solving this issue is to remove the dependency on subList method and update your recursive method to take List, startIndex and endIndex.

The other way to work around is to use a Thread safe implementation of List. You can take this route if you can change your list data structure.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Now, I seem to get an out-of-bounds exception... That's what I changed: https://pastebin.com/MZXa3jcJ

Comment: Along with the OutOfBoundsException, in the message you will see a index which caused the exception. Using that you should be able to figure out which boundary condition has an issue in your code.